# Changing part of a string

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a question about a batch-file. I have a script for connecting to a drive on an other pc on the network. Now i have to fill in the whole PC-Name. Every PC-name is the same but the last 3 to 5 numbers are different. For example
PC000012345, PC000001234 or PC000000123.

Now what i want is that if i put 3 or 4 numbers in the file that the other number(s) will be 0. For example I fill in 123 the output must be 00123 and if i fill in 1234 the output must be 01234. Is this possible within a command/commands?

Comment: yes, of course. Two steps: add a bunch of zeros, then cut the string to the desired length. [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) is the command to use for both steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
set X=1234
rem be sure to put enough zeros
set Y=0000000000%X%
echo %Y:~-5%
```

=>

```
01234
```

Comment: Thanks, i adapted the commands a little.. in the end i have this

set /p id="Enter ID: "
cls
set pcid=00000%id%
set fullpcid=%pcid:~-5%
set pcname=PC0000%fullpcid%

Echo Entered value:%fullpcid% , PC=%pcname%

If input is: 123 output is PC000000123, this is what i wanted to have! Thanks again